# List all files with certain extensions in Windows folder in a single call

Tags: batch-file

I would like to get all `.txt`, `.csv`, and `.xsl` files in a particular directory and write the filenames to a file.

I can just call it three times in a batch file like

```
dir /b *.csv > results.txt
dir /b *.xsl >> results.txt
dir /b *.txt >> results.txt
```

But can I do it in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a space to separate the file masks:

```
dir /b *.csv *.xsl *.txt > results.txt
```

Note that you can also sort the output, and the sort is applied across the entire list.  For example, to sort by name:

```
dir /b /o:n *.csv *.xsl *.txt > results.txt
```

Comment: `dir /b *.csv *.xsl *.txt > results.txt` There is no need for a semicolon as a space works.